# what does "ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Nickname.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE " mean for nick name?

Tags: android

Can any one tell me in detail : 
what is mean by "ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Nickname.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE ". 
In Android documentation it was given as "MIME type used when storing this in data table." 
Does MIMETYPE in thi context mean "string " value ?

Answer (score 0):

This is the mime-type internally used by the content resolver. You don't need to access to it.